# Strange rendering bug when using LuaLaTeX, Polyglossia, Cambria/Consolas font and/or texttt

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, debugging, rendering

I’ve found a rather strange bug, where the letter ‘å’ is sometimes (though very rarely) incorrectly rendered when using LuaLaTex. I’ve managed to reduce it to the following *minimal* document exhibiting the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{nynorsk}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\begin{document}

Here the word språket is rendered incorrectly. \texttt{Monospace.}

\end{document}
```

The output (using LuaLaTeX from TeX Live 2015 on a Windows system) is:

[image: Incorrect rendering.]

The strange thing is that I can make the problem go away by removing either *one* of the `\setdefaultlanguage`, `\setmainfont`, `\setmonofont` lines or the `\texttt` command, or by changing the ‘å’ to an ‘ø’ or an ‘æ’, or by changing LuaLaTeX to XeLaTeX:

[image: Correct rendering.]

So I don’t know if the problem is with Polyglossia, the Cambria font, the Consolas font, the `fontspec` package or LuaLaTeX. This makes it difficult to report as a bug. Any idea where the bug is and what causes it (and perhaps a workaround)?

Comment: I'd guess problem is in luaotfload but not sure. I see same in cygwin. If you compare logs with and without the \setdefaultlanguage setting then you see first real diff is `@firstpass
[][]\EU2/Cambria(0)/m/n/10 He-re the word språ-ket is rende-red incor-rect-ly`   here å  has been replaced by `a` followed by combining ring accent, and considered for hyphenation at that point.  otherwise I can't help much.

Comment: problem does not occur with xetex so it is unlikely to be the fonts at fault.

Comment: The guess that it is breaking in hyphenation pass possibly confirmed in that `\mbox{språket}` provides a workaround and causes the correct rendering.

Comment: How about a case-sensitive search-replace `å` with `{\aa}`?

Comment: It could be related to this bug: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/265

Comment: @UlrikeFischer looks like it but that's closed. I had wondered about trying to make a plain tex version just using luaotfload and \hyphenation{språ-ket} similar to the ones in that bug...

Comment: For what it's worth, I am *unable* to reproduce your problem on a system running MacOSX 10.10.4, MacTeX2015, and LuaLaTeX. Maybe it's a Windows-specific thing?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You could try if it is solved in the development version. https://github.com/phi-gamma/luaotfload (imho the master branch). (Last time I tried to use it I had a problem with the makefile and hadn't the time yet to find out how to get around it).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Excerpting from the log file: the two font files are `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Consolas.ttf` (version 2.00, from 2005) and `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Cambria.ttf` (version 2.00, from 2006). I'm afraid I have no way of ascertaining whether these fonts are the exact same ones as in a Windows-based system.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In which log file do you find the @firstpass information? It is natural that LaTeX would attempt the hyphenation only if `\setdefaultlanguage` is used, but if I leave `setdefaultlanguage{nynorsk}` and instead change the `\texttt` to (e.g.) `\textit`, the problem *also* disappears, which is strange.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Still, it does look like it’s related to hyphenation. If I change the language from `nynorsk` to `french`, the problem is still there, but if I change it to `german`, it disappears. And `french` suggests the same hyphenation point as `nynorsk` (‘språ-ket’), while `german` does not (‘språket’) (tested using `\showhyphens`).

Comment: It is certainly related to hyphenation. Like in my bug report one can trigger the effect simply with `\hyphenation{språ-ket}`. Btw: The negative space inserted has exaclty the same value as a space of the mono font (\kern -5.49805/ \glue 5.49805).

Comment: @Mico I can reproduce the bug with TeX Live 2015 on Linux and the fonts from Windows 8.  Cambria version 6.82 and Consolas version 5.34, both from 2013.  Maybe your fonts are too old?

Comment: @KarlOveHufthammer sorry i added `\tracingall` ( I _always_ add `\tracingall` :-) add it just before the paragraph

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer - I wouldn't have guessed that some of Microsoft's own fonts distributed with MacOSX are that much older than those distributed with Windows 8.

Comment: @Mico Me neither, but here you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using test releases of luatex 0.85 and the luatotfload from github sources, I get

[image]

So this should work in texlive 2016.

Comment: I’m still not sure exactly what was causing the problem, but can confirm that everything’s working fine in TeX Live 2016, so I’m marking this answer as the ‘accepted’.